# Relation between first order recurrence relations and functions?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

Suppose we have a recurrence relation of the form :

$$ a_{n+1} = \phi(a_n)$$

Where, $a_n \in R$,

I believe we can make statements about the recurrence, say eg, boundedness, monotonicity and so on, by analyzing $\phi$ as a single variable function on a suitable domain, and see it's derivatives. Am I onto something here?

Comment: Note that $a_n=\phi ^n(a_0)$. Thus, properties of $a_{n+1}$ are equivalent to the properties of iterations of $\phi$.

Comment: Some conditions are discussed in my answer to [Necessary or Sufficient conditions for a recursively defined sequence to be convergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351831/necessary-or-sufficient-conditions-for-a-recursively-defined-sequence-to-be-conv)

Comment: If  is bounded, then $a_n$ would be bounded as well by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526188/composite-bounded-functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, "yes"; longer answer, "yes, but you're not the first".

This type of sequence is called an "iterated function system". You're right that the derivative is important; it can be used to determine the stability of a fixed point of the system.

As a concrete example, you might want to solve an equation with this type of iterated system. Say you want to solve
$$x^3-6x^2+11x-6=0$$
(which, obviously, you can solve other ways, but we can use it as an example)

You can rewrite this as
$$x = \frac16 \left(x^2+11-\frac{6}{x}\right)$$

which you can think of as your type of sequence by writing
$$\phi(x) = \frac16 \left(x^2+11-\frac{6}{x}\right)$$

and defining $x_{n+1} = \phi\left(x_n\right)$

Fixed points of $\phi$ (ie those $x$ such that $\phi(x)=x$) are precisely the roots of the cubic (ie $1,2,3$). If we iterate the system for different starting points, which of these roots does it converge to? How is this related to the value of the derivative of $\phi$ at those points? Does it always converge? Can we rewrite the original equation in different ways to converge to a different root?

Of course, we can use this idea to solve more complicated equations too.

Some things you might want to look up are: iterated function systems, fixed point stability, fixed point iteration, Newton's method. Fractals based on these systems include bifurcation diagrams, Julia sets, the Mandelbrot set Barnsley's fern.

Hope that's useful!